# Automation of Meta Tags

Tags: meta-tags, automation

I want to know that can't I make different auto meta template for different products in different category. For example I've two categories sofa and table now I want a different meta for sofa products and different meta for table product.

Comment: do you want product wise meta tags?

Comment: @Olive: have you the solution ? Does this helps ?

Answer (score 1):

In Magento admin panel **Catalog->Categories -> Manage Categories-> Select a category**.

There will be option to provide the page title, meta keyword and description for each and every category

Answer (score 0):

You can use meta information of product.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For generating `DYNAMIC METAs` for products, you should Override `head.phtml` template for `PRODUCT VIEW` pages.

See here for : [How to override head.phtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373670/how-to-rewrite-head-phtml-in-magento)

Then apply your custom logic for METAs in that file